# Doctrine - Get entity and relationships in one query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Am I missing a point with Doctrine? It's been very useful for some scenarios, but for the basic scenario of retrieving an entity using an Id (say using find() or findOneBy()) why do you see a query being fired off for every relationship to populate the main entity's properties?

Surely with the mapping/annotations I've created, Doctrine should be capable of a few joins and one query, without having to write a DQL query for the retrieval of each entity.

Or, as I'm predicting, have I missed the point somewhere!

Comment: Give us an example of your code. Doctrine is surely capable of doing what you described via single query...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the aliases of related entities to `select` part of your query.

Let’s say, you have `Book` related one-to-many to `Cover`, and you want so select some books with their covers.

With query builder, use:

```
->createQueryBuilder()
->select("book, cover")
->from("Book", "book")
->leftJoin("book.covers", "cover")
```

With query, use:

```
SELECT book, cover FROM Book book LEFT JOIN book.covers cover
```

As the result, you will receive collections of `Book` with prepopulated `$covers` collection.

Comment: As you can imagine I've got a lot further with this now, but thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Because the relationships are hydrated only when needed - by default Doctrine uses a lazy-loading strategy.
If you already know that you will access the related entities, you should build a DQL query that retrieves the record AND the related entities.

Comment: As I suspected and hoped wasn't the case. On reflection, I guess Doctrine can't KNOW which relationships you want and when without a custom query. A custom repository and method it is then?

Comment: Yes - just consider this as an optimization...in fact you should know in your application workflow if (and when) you will need the related entities.