# Left join encounters "Call to a member function add() on a non-object in PersistentCollection"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create a simple query to get all related entities in one query (see [Doctrine - Get entity and relationships in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13315768/390177)). For some reasons doctrine encounters an error:

> Call to a member function add() on a non-object in
>   PersistentCollection

Full stacktrace:

```
Error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection.php line 177
    at n/a
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection.php line 177
    at Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection->hydrateAdd()
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php line 456
    at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateRowData()
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php line 179
    at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator->hydrateAllData()
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator.php line 140
    at Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator->hydrateAll()
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php line 804
    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->execute()
        in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php line 574
    at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getResult()
```

Group mapping:

```
Group:
  type: entity
  table: groups
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  oneToMany:
    influences:
      targetEntity: Influence
      mappedBy: group
      cascade: [ "persist" ]
```

Influence mapping:

```
Influence:
  type: entity
  table: influences
  id:
    organisation:
      associationKey: true
    group:
      associationKey: true

  fields:
    influence:
      type: integer

  manyToOne:
    organisation:
      targetEntity: Organisation
      inversedBy: influences
    group:
      targetEntity: Group
      inversedBy: influences
```

And here is my query builder logic:

```
$builder->select('g, i')
->from('Group', 'g')
->join('g.game', 'game')
->leftJoin('g.influences', 'i', Join::WITH, 'i.organisation = :org')
->setParameter('org', $organisation)
->orderBy('g.name')
->getQuery();
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Don't know about the error message but you are using a where clause on your joined object so you won't get any groups without an influence.  You question is a bit unclear since it appears that your query works?  So where is add being called?

Comment: I have added the stack trace, the query itself works partial if I echo the sql and run it manually. Influence used a composed primary key containing organisation id and group id. How shall I pass the organisation object?

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint with the WHERE clause, I have found the right "constellation" to generate the query, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this issue is in general very easy.

I have created different entity classes and added at some points default values like empty array to the class field.
This results into the error above.

I have done it to test my business logic local without any database connection or similar with Behat.

Removing the empty `array()` solved my problem.

To be compatible with Behat I need a setter for the field to set again an empty array or extend this class and add a constructor to default the field.
Perhaps someone else have another idea about this.

Comment: Yes sir! u saved my day!

Comment: Probably saved me an afternoon of debugging. Thank you!